# Corrections to definite integral involving some special function

Tags: definite-integrals, asymptotics, approximation, closed-form, bessel-functions

I get the standard result for the following integration:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\exp ik[\sqrt{s^2+x^2}]}{\sqrt{s^2+x^2}}\,dx=i\pi H_0^1 (ks)$$.

Where, $H_0^1(x)$ stands for the Hankel function of first kind with order $0$.

I can not derive this standard result. Would you kindly help me?

Further,  I want to find out the same integral but within different limit (finite range) such as $$\int_{-L}^L\frac{\exp ik[\sqrt{s^2+x^2}]}{\sqrt{s^2+x^2}}\,dx$$ where $L$ is some finite length.

Would you kindly suggest me how I can get the desired value from the given result. 
Thanking you

Comment: Sir, sorry for tagging..Actually, it would be better, if I get the closed form answer.

Comment: Thank you Sir..

Comment: Please see Watson's text: A treatise on the theory of Bessel functions.

Comment: I'm not familiar with $H_0^1$ - what function is that?

Comment: Sorry Sir, I did not mention it in my post. I have edited right now. $H_0^1(x)$ represents the Hankel function of first kind with order zero.Awaiting for your further suggestion....Thank You...